# Algebra with two quadratics

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I go about solving the following problem:

> Let $4a^2 + 7 + 4a = 6b - b^2 - 3$. Find $\frac{b}{a}$ ?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: First find $a,b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint.

It's $$(2a+1)^2+(b-3)^2=0.$$
Now, use $x^2+y^2=0\Leftrightarrow x=y=0$.